# I can't figure out why my @font-face isn't working? As far as I can tell everything is appropriately set up but it won't read

Tags: css, web, font-face

if it's not clear, I'm really new to web design, and I'm trying to put together my first web page. Specifically, a tumblr theme. I found a very handy guide, and I've been following that, celebrating my mini victories, but I just hit a road block in trying to use a custom font.

According to the tutorial, she grabbed a link online- but I want to use a font I've already installed on my computer. So I used the @font-face assignment, which wasn't covered in the original tutorial... I'm sure I've got it set up appropriately, but I don't know enough to figure out what I'm doing wrong or how to correct it. any help would be really appreciated.

I've tried single quotes as well as quotation marks, and a bunch of other little things, but I just can't figure out how to connect the two values.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
------CSS and Java content here------
<title>{Many Hues Acres}{block:PostSummary}, {PostSummary}
{/block:PostSummary}</title>
{block:Description}<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />{/block:Description}
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}" />
<meta name="color:Background" content="#000000">

<style type="text/css">
 @font-face { 
  font-family: fitamint; 
 src:url(fitamintscript.otf); 
} 

body {
      word-wrap: break-word
      background-attachment: fixed;
   background-image: url(Tile2.png);
}
#sidebar {
      background-color: white;
      width: 500px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 600px;
      left: 300px;
}
#sidebar .title {
      font-family:fitamint;   
   font-size: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      padding:10px;
}

</style>
</head>
------HTML content here------
<body>

<div id="sidebar">
<div class="title"><a href="/">title</a></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The font will have to be in the project's directory, it won't read it from the install directory on your computer. Put "fitamintscript.otf" in the same folder as index.html

Comment: Unfortunately I already relocated the original file into the index, I still couldn't get it to read.